# What did Bernard Stiegler say about technology always progressing?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-technology

My uncle was reading Stiegler right before he died and he was saying something that Stiegler said technological advancement never ends. As a budding futurist; I find this very intriguing and would like to know more. My uncle said I couldn’t handle his work but I’d like to try. Can anyone help and/or direct me?

Answer (score 1):

According to reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technics_and_Time,_1) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Stiegler):

> Stiegler argues that "technics" forms the horizon of human existence. This fact has been suppressed throughout the history of philosophy, which has never ceased to operate on the basis of a distinction between episteme and tekhne. The thesis of the book is that the genesis of technics corresponds not only to the genesis of what is called "human" but of temporality as such, and that this is the clue toward understanding the future of the dynamic process in which the human and the technical consists.

> Part I conducts a reading of approaches to the history of technology and the origin of hominisation, in particular by André Leroi-Gourhan, Gilbert Simondon, and Bertrand Gille. The outcome of this reading is the thought that history cannot be thought according to the idea that humanity is the "subject" of this history and technology simply the object. When it comes to the relation between the human and the technical, the "who" and the "what" are in an undecidable relation.

> La technique et le temps (3 vols.). The Technics and Time series outlines the heart of Stiegler's philosophical project, and in particular his theses that the role of technics has been repressed throughout the history of philosophy, and that technics, as organised inorganic matter, and as essentially a form of memory, is constitutive of human temporality. The series contains extensive readings of the works of André Leroi-Gourhan, Martin Heidegger, Edmund Husserl, and Immanuel Kant. It also contains his explication of the "cinematic constitution of consciousness," as well as his thesis that human beings are essentially "adoptive" and "prosthetic" creatures.

So apparently Stiegler holds some unusual personified view of technics in relation to humanity, and emphasized technics (technology) is essentially a form of memory which *consists of temporality*, meaning technology is always progressing. It's very much like Hegelian historicity of the dialectic relation between humanity and technics which technics may *sublate* and *create* itself continuously forward...